# Fill WriteableBitmap more efficient

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, flood-fill

I create WriteableBitmaps on the fly. Is this the efficient and best way to do it?

```
var image = new WriteableBitmap(128, 128);
var colorBuffer = Enumerable.Repeat(
    new[] {this.ImageColor.B, this.ImageColor.G, this.ImageColor.R, this.ImageColor.A},
    image.PixelHeight*image.PixelWidth).SelectMany(b => b).ToArray();

using(var stream = image.PixelBuffer.AsStream())                    
    stream.Write(colorBuffer, 0, colorBuffer.Length);
```

at the end, i return the image as an `ImageSource` object. so maybe there is also an other way to create an `ImageSource` with uniform color.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps yes, the most powerful aspect of WritableBitmap is the Render() method which allows rendering a UIElement to the bitmap. This can be used to transform images (scale, etc.) or to render overlays, etc. With WriteableBitmap you can also convert the user controls or any custom controls to an image.